# I am passing input DOM element's value as an argument in typescript function but it is returning empty string

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, dom

```
const ol = document.querySelector('ol')
const input: HTMLInputElement = document.querySelector('input')
const button = document.querySelector('button')

let toDoList: Array<String> = []
 
addToList(input!.value)

function addToList(todo: String) {
    button.onclick = () => {
        console.log()
        toDoList.push(todo)
        renderItems()
    }
}

function renderItems() {
    ol.innerHTML = ''
    toDoList.forEach(todo => {
        ol.innerHTML += `<li>${todo}</li>`
    })
    console.log(toDoList)
}
```

1. I am making a to do app in typescript. i want the function to get the input value as argument

Comment: What is returning an empty string?

Comment: Any time the button is clicked, you should be getting the `input.value` again, not using the `todo` passed into the method, which will not change.

Comment: I want to pass input.value to addToList function as a string. Then want to use inside that function

Comment: If you do that, then the value will never change.

Comment: Ah got it. Thanks ))